# Why does this not tell me how long the vector of strings is?

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<string> SS;

    SS.push_back("The number is 10");
    cout << SS.size();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the output is 1. Why is it not the length of the string?

Comment: Because your string is in the vector, e.g. `SS[0]` - so `SS[0].size` would be the length of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does tell you how long the vector of strings is. The length of a vector means the number of items in tt, in this case `1`.

To get the length of the first item in the vector, write `cout << SS[0].size();` .

Comment: @arc_lupus you need to use the "foot in the door" method... make a one-word answer immediately and then edit it within the grace period

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the size of the vector via accessing `SS.size()`. If you want to get the size of the string, use `SS[0].size()`. Then you're accessing the first element, e.g. your first pushed-back string.
If you want to get the length of the last inserted element, then use `SS[SS.size()-1].size()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SS.size()
```

would give you number of elements inserted in vector.

To get length of particular string you can use:-

```
SS[i].length();
```

Answer (score 0):

the size() method gives the size of the vector, e.g the amount of strings within it (with it one, because you pushed only 1 string)
try SS.front().length() to get your string length

Answer (score -1):

Because `SS.size()` returns the number of elements in your vector `SS`, which is 1 because you have put one string in it.

If you want to know the length of the string in your vector, you could do the following:

```
int length = strlen(SS[0])
```

`SS[0]` will return the string at position 0, which you have entered. Strlen will return the length of that string.

Edit: to use `strlen` you need to `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Why use `strlen`, when you can use `size()` which is a class-member of strings?

Comment: `strlen(SS[0])` is a type error. `strlen` takes a `const char *`, not a `string`. Also, `strlen` does not return `int`, it returns `size_t`, which can easily overflow an `int`.